# How to solve excel row and column difficulty?

Tags: python, r, excel

i have a problem with excel. I downloaded a csv that has data not separated by comma or other and are not divided by row or single cell. Here is a screenshot. How can i divide this data in python or R to manage them separated one by one?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: No pictures of code or data please. Post e.g. the first three or five lines of the csv-file as text.

Comment: Your data appears to be pipe (`|`) delimited with inconsistent row length.

Comment: Open your file in a text editor. Select the first five to ten lines and copy. Edit your question. Paste those lines into your question. Highlight the pasted lines in your question. Press the format-as-code button. Save your edits. That will give us an accurate view of your data.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of columns is the same on all lines, this should work:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('my_full_filepath.csv', sep ='|')
print(df.info())
```

Otherwise, you can try, as a first approach,

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_full_filepath.csv', sep ='|', error_bad_lines = False)
print(df.info())
```

If there are data dropped, you might have to try opening your dataframe with an argument passing the maximal number of columns of your file.
This can be done, for example by :

```
n = int('number of my columns')
df = pd.read_csv('my_full_file_path.csv', sep ='|', names = range(n))
```